# Onmouseout and OnmouseOver image with CSS Sprite

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have the following image and i want to turn it to CSS Sprite:

`<img height="32" width="139" border="0" onmouseout="this.src='/images/top_menu/nav03.gif';" onmouseover="this.src='/images/top_menu/nav04.gif';" src="/images/top_menu/nav03.gif" />`

My CSS is

```
.sprite-top_menu {
background-image: url(top_menu.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*display: block;*/
```

}

```
.sprite-nav03-top_menu {
width: 139px;
height: 32px;
background-position: 0 -32px;
```

}

```
.sprite-nav04-top_menu {
width: 139px;
height: 32px;
background-position: -139px -32px;
```

}

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tags don't lend themselves very well for sprites, I recommend doing something like this:

```
<div class="sprite-top_menu"></div>
```

CSS

```
.sprite-top_menu {
  background: url(top_menu.png) no-repeat;
  width: 139px;
  height: 32px;
  background-position: 0 -32px;
}

.sprite-top_menu:hover {
  background-position: -139px -32px;
}
```